# How do I Refresh Data inside the ListView on my form everytime the time ticker event occurs C#

Tags: c#, listview

I am currently stuck trying to get the Listview box to refresh to show updated balances. Would anyone know how I can refresh the listView box with all the data inside it every time the timeticker event occurs so that the balances get updated ?  I have tried listview.Refresh.  That doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: When you added data to the LV, you added strings not references to something, perhaps in a DB.  You will have to remove them all and repopulate.  Or use a DGV and a proper datasource

Comment: I see so if I use reference variables instead would that work ?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Could you provide us some xaml and c# code. I would say that you are not using ObservableCollection or it is not binded to your ListView. But that is just guessing.

Comment: If it is Winforms, that LV doesnt support data binding - they are all strings

Comment: private void LoadListViewItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                if (customer.Accounts[i] is LineOfCreditAccount)
                {
                    
                    listViewAccountBalances.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] 
                                                    {customer.Accounts[i].ToString(), 
                                                     customer.Accounts[i].Balance.ToString()}));
                }
             
            }
        }

Comment: This is the Tick event handler for the Listview:  private void timerProcessTransactions_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (transactionCollection.Count > 0)
            {

                
                transactionCollection.ProcessPendingTransactions();
                label2.Text = transactionCollection[0].Status.ToString();
                listViewAccountBalances.Refresh();



            } 
        }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming you are not using databinding, learn a little bit about it as it seems most relevant in your simple case: [DataBinding Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

Once you bind your ListView to the source, attach a handler ([Event Handler Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) for the timeticker and call Refresh() on the ListView inside your timeticker handler.

Comment: Great, Thanks very much.  Will take a look into this now.